# Wrong Formatting while reading complex input data

Tags: file, io, fortran, format

There is a file with a line format:

> string, char char integer

which I'm trying to read and store in arrays using the following code:

```
module MyModyle

contains

subroutine ReadFileIntoArrays (filename, name_arr, kWh_arr)
    implicit none

    ! function parameters
    character (len = *), intent (in) :: filename
    character, dimension(:), intent (out) :: name_arr
    integer, dimension(:), intent (out) :: kWh_arr

    ! variables contained on a single line
    character (len = 1) :: first_name, second_name
    character (len = 20) :: surname
    integer :: consumption

    integer :: arr_index = 1, ios_status = 0, unit_number = 1
    character (len = 30) :: fullname

    open (unit = unit_number, file = filename, status = 'old', action = 'read')

    do
        ! read a line from the file
        read (unit_number, iostat = ios_status) surname, first_name, second_name, consumption

        ! check input validity
        if (ios_status > 0) then
            print *, "Wrong input format!"
            print *, surname, first_name, second_name, consumption
            exit
        else if (ios_status < 0) then ! end of file
            print *, "End of file reached."
            exit
        else ! populate arrays
            ! concatenate full name
            fullname = surname
            fullname = fullname//','
            fullname = fullname//first_name
            fullname = fullname//'.'
            fullname = fullname//second_name
            fullname = fullname//'.'

            name_arr(arr_index) = fullname
            kWh_arr(arr_index) = consumption

            arr_index = arr_index + 1
       end if
    end do

    close (unit_number)
end subroutine ReadFileIntoArrays

end module MyModule

! --------------------------------------------------------------- !

program MyMain
    use MyModule
    implicit none

    integer, dimension(10) :: consumption
    character, dimension(10) :: names
    character (11) :: filename = 'clients.txt'

    call ReadFileIntoArrays(filename, names, consumption)
end program MyMain
```

To no avail, all I get is: `Wrong Input Format!`.

What is wrong with the file reading and how to do it right?

---

<sup>Note: After a research all I find is posts of simple file reading involving mostly columns of numbers.</sup>

Comment: You are attempting unformatted input on a file connected for formatted transfers.

Comment: @francescalus This is indeed part of the problem, thank you. Could you please suggest a standard way of reading a line with the specified format: do I use additional variables as above, or do I write directly in the arrays. If you post it as an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: Unless you have particularly demanding requirements (robustness or an expectation of "special" characters in the input) you could possibly get away with list-directed formatting: `fmt=*`).

Comment: @francescalus I'm trying for the last hour: `(surname, first_name, second_name, consumption)`, or reading a `line` and separating (`pos = scan(line, '0123456789')`) on the first digit... and getting nonsense values. It turns out to be more of a parsing problem...I don't know if I should post it as an additional / separate question?

Comment: I suggest opening a new question with a detailed description of your format and the data.

Comment: @VladimirF But, haven't I done it literally in the second line of the post? Or   , do you mean something else by _format_ and _data_. The file is consisted of lines of:  `string` COMMA `single character` WS `single character` WS `integer`.

Comment: I meant the *format string* you tried when you got the nonsense values. And it is always better to show the actual data, not just describe them.

Comment: @VladimirF I've posted a new post considering only the parsing. I read about format strings and the associated format specifiers, especially those considering characters,but there seems to be no example that shows how to apply them to read in manner similar to my problem.