# How to read and parse a line from file?

Tags: file, parsing, fortran

There is a file consisted of lines in the following format:

```
John, D E       100
Bob, F I        200
Oli, G H       1500
...
```

in general:

> `string`, `char` `char` `integer`

The file needs to be read and stored in two arrays of which the first should store the string and characters<sup>1</sup> and the second should store the integer.

How could this be done?

---

<sup>An initial attempt is made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157080/wrong-formatting-while-reading-complex-input-data).</sup>

<sup>1. Concatenated into single string as they are with the comma and the white spaces.</sup>

---

Comment: Is the integer guaranted to occupy those three columns?

Comment: @VladimirF The integer is at most for digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in the input file are delimited by whitespaces or commas, we can read them using list-directed input (`fmt=*`), as suggested in the comments in the linked question, such that

```
read (funit, [fmt =] *, iostat = ios) surname, first_name, second_name, consumption
```

where the part "fmt =" is optional. The following is a slightly modified version of the original code in the linked page (please see comments in the code for more details):

```
module MyModule
    implicit none  !<-- this propagates to all routines in this module
contains

subroutine ReadFileIntoArrays (filename, name_arr, kWh_arr, ndata)

    character(*), intent(in) :: filename     !<-- an assumed-length string
    character(*), intent(out) :: name_arr(:) !<-- an array of assumed-length strings
    integer, intent(out) :: kWh_arr(:), ndata

    character :: first_name, second_name  !<-- a single char
    character(50) :: surname              !<-- a string of 50 chars
    integer :: consumption, funit, ios, idx

    funit = 10  ! use >= 10 (or open( newunit=funit, ... ) for recent compilers)
    open (funit, file = filename, status = 'old')

    idx = 0
    do
        read (funit, fmt = *, iostat = ios) &   !<-- "&" means line continuation
                surname, first_name, second_name, consumption

        ! "fmt = *" (list-directed input) tells the compiler
        ! to use whitespaces/commas as delimiters.

        if (ios > 0) then
            print *, "Wrong input format!" ; exit
        else if (ios < 0) then
            print *, "finished reading data." ; exit
        else
            idx = idx + 1
            if (idx > size( name_arr )) stop "size of name_arr(:) too small"

            ! trim() chops trailing spaces in a string
            name_arr( idx ) = trim(surname)//','//first_name//'.'//second_name//'.'
            kWh_arr( idx ) = consumption
        end if
    end do
    ndata = idx

    close (funit)
end subroutine

end module

program MyMain
    use MyModule
    implicit none
    integer :: consumption( 10 ), ndata, idx
    character(50) :: names( 10 )  !<-- an array of size 10 (each element = 50-char string)
    character(200) :: filename    !<-- a string of 200 chars

    filename = "clients.txt"
    names = ""
    consumption = 0

    call ReadFileIntoArrays (filename, names, consumption, ndata)

    print "(2a20)", "name", "consumption"
    do idx = 1, ndata
        print "(a20,i20)", trim( names( idx ) ), consumption( idx )
    enddo
end program
```

Then, with the input in the question, the output becomes

```
 finished reading data.
                name         consumption
           John,D.E.                 100
            Bob,F.I.                 200
            Oli,G.H.                1500
```

Comment: But I guess for this kind of work, other tools (python pandas or excel-like tool ??) might be much easier to use...

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Especially the clarifications via additional comments.

Comment: Glad if it works :) For further info, these pages may be very useful http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/topics http://www.fortran90.org/index.html# http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html